# Firefox loads and plays same .ogv file twice concurrently when with 'autoplay'

Tags: firefox, html5-audio, ogg, autoplay

I have an ogg vorbis file set up with the HTML5 `<audio>` tag.
The file is requested twice by Firefox (3.6.13), but with the 'autoplay' option both of the requested files play.
When I pause, one of the tracks stops but other continues. When I press play again then both tracks play, albeit out of sync now.

All works great with webkit and opera.
In Firefox without 'autoplay' the ogg file is requested twice but only one plays and all appears normal. But I need the 'autoplay' functionality in this scenario.

My html:
`<audio autoplay controls">`
        `<source src="/media/BetterDays.ogv" type="audio/ogg; codec=vorbis"></source>`
        `<source src="/media/BetterDays.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source>`
`</audio>`

My jQuery:

```
if(!!document.createElement('audio').canPlayType) {
    audio = $('audio').get(0);
    $(audio).removeAttr("controls");
    $(audio).bind('play',function() {
      $("#playtoggle").addClass('playing');   
    }).bind('pause ended', function() {
      $("#playtoggle").removeClass('playing');    
    });   

    $("#playtoggle").click(function() {     
      if (audio.paused) { audio.play(); } 
      else { audio.pause(); }     
    });
```

I really appreciate any help one could offer. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue. It only happens in Firefox and when I turn off autoplay for the video the issue goes away. Have you had any success in resolving this since posting this?

Comment: I just turned off autoplay and started it on document load with jquery:  set audio.play() on $(document).ready

Comment: One question that might be silly... Why do you declare controls for the audio element, and remove them later?

Answer (score 2):

do it like this, html 5 tags are still a bit buggy, but GOOD ol' javascript will do the trick

```
<script>
give your audio tag an id, in my example it will be audiobox

function play() {
    document.getElementById('audiobox').play();
  }
  play();
 </script>
```